# GeoServer 2.17 - added Shapefile with geometry of type "3D Polygon", rendering fails exception "Must have at least 2 spatial dimensions"

Tags: geoserver, shapefile

I've downloaded a public shapefile and added it to Geoserver 2.16 just fine. QGIS as well. I added it to a GeoServer 2.17 as well, but when trying to preview, it causes the following exception

```
2020-05-22 08:28:38,325 ERROR [renderer.lite] - Must have at least 2 spatial dimensions
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must have at least 2 spatial dimensions
    at org.locationtech.jts.geom.impl.PackedCoordinateSequence.<init>(PackedCoordinateSequence.java:57)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.LiteCoordinateSequence.<init>(LiteCoordinateSequence.java:151)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.LiteCoordinateSequence.cloneGeometry(LiteCoordinateSequence.java:371)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.LiteCoordinateSequence.cloneGeometry(LiteCoordinateSequence.java:316)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.LiteCoordinateSequence.cloneGeometry(LiteCoordinateSequence.java:302)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.LiteCoordinateSequence.cloneGeometry(LiteCoordinateSequence.java:384)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.LiteCoordinateSequence.cloneGeometry(LiteCoordinateSequence.java:306)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.LiteCoordinateSequence.cloneGeometry(LiteCoordinateSequence.java:312)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.LiteShape2.<init>(LiteShape2.java:124)
    at org.geotools.geometry.jts.LiteShape2.<init>(LiteShape2.java:99)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processSymbolizers(StreamingRenderer.java:3000)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processFeature(StreamingRenderer.java:2807)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.drawPlain(StreamingRenderer.java:2644)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2243)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:900)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:601)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:275)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:135)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:749)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:300)
```

ogrinfo indicates the layer contains 3D polygons.  And I see each point does have three coordinates.  I don't know if the third value is in feet or meters.

To try this yourself, go here: https://openhartford-hartfordgis.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/building and download the shapefile.  Add it to GeoServer 2.17, Preview it with Openlayers, and you'll get the exception.

I've worked around this by using QGIS and Exporting to a new Shapefile, but specifying that the geometries should be Polygons.  This 2 dimensional export renders fine in GeoServer 2.17.

Comment: FYI - when exported to a GPKG, which ogrinfo indicates the layer geometry is "3D Multi Polygon", when added to Geoserver in this way it renders fine.  So it seems the "3D Polygon" geometry in a Shapefile is not rendering properly.  I will change the title of the question to more accurately describe this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created an [issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6599) for this.

**Update**

Nightly releases of [2.18.x](http://geoserver.org/release/master/) and [2.17.x](http://geoserver.org/release/2.17.x/) from 25/5/2020 will contain the bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in a similar issue and fixed it by explicitly stating that I wanted 2D values only when reading the shapefile containing 3D points:

```
val query = Query(typeName, Filter.INCLUDE)
query.hints.add(Hints(Hints.FEATURE_2D, true))

return dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName)
           .getFeatures(query)
```

The code above is in Kotlin, but you can see the Java version and original documentation here: https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/data/featuresource.html